# String doesn't appear in class when using constructor

Tags: c#, string, class

I have made monopoly game in C# for a month already and i finished everything, i have only one problem from start. There are 2 forms. First one is where you select how many players are playing and typing their names. Second is the game, and i have tested, it passes player names from form1 to form2, but it seems like it doesn't apply it when i use constructor for class Player.
It looks like this 
Form 2:

```
    public static string PlayerName1;
    public static string PlayerName2;
    public static string PlayerName3;
    public static string PlayerName4;
    public static Player Player1 = new Player(0, PlayerName1, 1, 10000);
    public static Player Player2 = new Player(1, PlayerName2, 1, 10000);
    public static Player Player3 = new Player(2, PlayerName3, 1, 10000);
    public static Player Player4 = new Player(3, PlayerName4, 1, 10000);
```

As i said, PlayerName (all of them) works perfectly in form2 i tested it in label and it shows it right, so it isn't problem passing it from form1

Now the Player class code:

```
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Field;
    public int Money;
    public Player(int id, string name, int field, int money)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Field = field;
        Money = money;
    }
```

So now this is where i use those values in form2:

```
 private void update()
    {
        switch (turn)
        {
            case 0: PlayerName.Text = Player1.Name; 
            Money.Text = Convert.ToString(Player1.Money) + "$"; 
            break;

            case 1: PlayerName.Text = Player2.Name; 
            Money.Text = Convert.ToString(Player1.Money) + "$";                                 
            break;

            case 2: PlayerName.Text = Player3.Name;
            Money.Text = Convert.ToString(Player1.Money) + "$"; 
            break;

            case 3: PlayerName.Text = Player4.Name;
            Money.Text = Convert.ToString(Player1.Money) + "$"; 
            break;
        }
    }
```

PlayerName and Money in form2 are labels, Money label works perfectly with every "update" but PlayerName label is always empty. It is visible and it has text "Name" in it when i open Form2 but after first "update" it is empty and stays like that until i restart program. I also use Player.PlayerName in message boxes when paying rent from one player to another and it also doesn't work there... Hopefully someone can help me, i have to finish this by tomorrow, it's not like i'll get lesser grade for this but i want to everything be perfectly :)

Comment: From what you show above it looks like you're just passing empty strings. Try filling out the names then initializing the player objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As i said, PlayerName (all of them) works perfectly in form2

They surely do, when the form is created and its method invoked.

```
public static Player Player1 = new Player(0, PlayerName1, 1, 10000);
```

This static initialization unfortunately takes place at the very beginning of the form's lifetime. At this moment, the `PlayerName1` is empty yet. You possibly change it somewhere *later* but too late, the change isn't magically copied to the player object by itself.

The workaround is simple, make sure you updat the name property when the name is known.

```
// somewhere you somehow learn the name
PlayerName1 = ... 

// update accordingly
Player1.Name = PlayerName1;
```

Comment: Right, I would also suggest to get rid of those static variables for the player name. They are useless if you have already 4 static Player objects

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! I defined public static string playername in form1 and just used it in constructor (form1.PlayerName1) instead of PlayerName1 defined in form2 and it works well! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you should init string values.

```
public static string PlayerName1 ="Bob";
```